# Outer Component Spacing

Tags: css, reactjs

Reading Chris Pearce's [Handling spacing in a UI component library](https://medium.com/fed-or-dead/handling-spacing-in-a-ui-component-library-70f3b22ec89) I found this:

> ... components need to be highly self-contained so that they have zero dependency on any particular UI context or other components. Each component should be able to be dropped anywhere in the UI and it’ll just work.

Let's say I have a `Button` component, for the button to "work" it makes sense for me to have this component have an outer margin, the minimum space around the button for it to "work" ("work", as in look good, and not smashed against another element).

But then the article goes on the opposite direction, saying:

> Components that have outer spacing applied by default can be problematic.

This, and the entirety of the article, arguments the opposite, the `Button` shouldn't have that outer space and we could use other techniques to set it: An `Spacer` component, a `Wrapper` component, etc.

---

Back to the basics:

```
<div id="container">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>


<Container>
  <Paragraph>Hello</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>World</Paragraph>
</Container>
```

In this case, I think, it should be the p tag (or a `Paragraph` component) the one in charge of ensuring that there is a space between itself and other elements.

This article and other's I've found seem to argue the opposite: `p` should care only within itself, and depending on where P is used, we should handle spacing differently.

---

**Actual Question:** Is there a documented best practice or consensus on how to handle outer component spacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The references you've cited from my article are not contradicting each other as you've implied:

> But then the article goes on the opposite direction, saying:

However, I can see how you might have interpreted it that way.

Basically what I mean by this:

> Each component should be able to be dropped anywhere in the UI and it’ll just work.

Is that baking in outer component spacing can lead to scalability issues as you're making your components less reusable (portable) as they are too opinionated about the contexts that they are being used in or used in ***today***…

Today your `<Button>` component is implemented in the same two contexts across your entire UI where baking in outer spacing makes sense. Tomorrow, however, a new context springs up where that spacing doesn't make sense. You could turn off the spacing in this case, e.g.:

```
<Button spacing={false} />
```

But what if it happens again, and again? This is where things start to get ugly as now `spacing={false}` is the default but obviously it doesn't make sense for a consumer to apply that each time so you now have to do a search and replace of all instances of `<Button>` to remove `spacing={false}` which might not be too bad if you're on a small app but imagine working on a design system where you're providing highly reusable UI components to a bunch of teams working on individual apps. Even if out of 10 different implementations (contexts) of `<Button>` 8 required outer spacing I would still not bake it in.

That's the crux of it really, just have `<Button>` only be concerned with itself so that it's more reusable (portable) and I'd argue easier to consume and document. If patterns emerge where your `<Button>` component needs to be composed in certain ways I'd most likely look at creating another component to handle those concerns.

The Lego analogy is a nice way of thinking about it. Each component is a  piece of Lego that can be assembled in many different ways that as a whole form a system. The spacing component [covered here](https://medium.com/fed-or-dead/handling-spacing-in-a-ui-component-library-70f3b22ec89#56fe) is just another Lego piece taking care of one specific part of said system. I think it can be related back to certain computer science design principles such as:

- [Component-based software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering)
- [Composability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composability)
- [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

On your paragraph example, the way I'd handle the spacing between each paragraph is by letting another component take care of it, e.g.:

```
<LongFormCopy>
    <P>Bla bla</P>
    <P>Bla bla</P>
</LongFormCopy>
```

The CSS:

```
.c-long-form-copy p:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: var(--spacing-base);
}
```

It's rare you're going to have something like a paragraph sitting in your view (or your Container components) standalone, e.g.:

```
<SomeComponent>
<SomeOtherComponent>
<P>Bla bla</P>
<P>Bla bla</P>
<SomeOtherComponent>
```

My approach would be to encapsulate them into a component as it'll be representing some sort of UI pattern that will most likely come up again. Also in application UI's long form copy is rare hence why I like having a `<LongFormCopy>` component as on the rare occasions where your app features long form copy you can handle all those typography concerns in the one place. This is one of the exceptions where using a spacing component wouldn't make sense covered in my article [here](https://medium.com/fed-or-dead/handling-spacing-in-a-ui-component-library-70f3b22ec89#319d).

Maybe send a screenshot(s) of your `<Button>` implementation(s) as I'm curious.

To your direct question:

> Is there a documented best practice or consensus on how to handle outer component spacing?

I'm not sure they'll ever be the one source of truth on how to do this. If you find baking spacing in works for you whilst being highly scalable and maintainable then great keep doing it .

Comment: I didn't mean they contradict each other, I was clearly fishing for something that supported my ideas and got excited only to stand corrected as I read the entire article. Thanks for responding in great detail, I see your point and the more I've read on the topic, the more I'm convinced this is the way to go. | There is nothing special in Button, the issue actually arrived with Avatar, but I just generalized with Button or a paragraph tag.

Comment: Ok no worries and good luck with it! Glad I could help and I certainly don't have all the answers and I find this stuff quite challenging esp when you add responsive to the mix .

Comment: I had similar question, and this response resolved all my doubts, thanks @crite for great and complete response.

Answer (score 2):

There is no best practice at the moment. As I understand it. I don't mean to promote but I've been talking about component first design/development which actually tackles this issue (https://medium.com/@jerrylowm/front-end-development-is-like-figure-skating-it-rewards-to-be-more-technical-than-artistic-784323079131).

In a nutshell component first design/development is very similar to Chris Pearce's method (I have to finish the article), but the only difference is that the `<button>` example will include the outer margin. BUT! It might not, why?

The concept is component design so it really depends if you treat the button as its own component or not. Example, if the button is a CTA of a marketing banner then the banner itself might be the component. Where as if its a calendar button that's placed all over the app the button itself maybe the component. In the example that you showed:

```
<div id="container">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

I would have a class name for the parent and treat it as a component and space the paragraphs in it accordingly, because most of the time paragraphs require different amount of spacing. My approach:

```
<div id="container" class="body-text>
  <p class="body-text__p">Hello</p>
  <p class="body-text__p>World</p>
</div>
```

The CSS with BEM:

```
.body-text {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.body-text__p + .body-text__p {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Once, again because there's no best practice everybody has their own approach to tackle this issue. I think if you start creating spacing just around `<p>` you're approaching it more of an atomic level which I think works for some application but not all.

Comment: CTA = call to action, it took me a while. From your article: " If your component needs 20px (margin) around it, it has to be built into the component." This means that for the ones you consider actual components (calendar button, marketing banner, etc.) you would add the margin if needed? | I like the "component first" mentality, but I might take it a step further and consider the background-image and call-to-action button inside the marketing banner, component as well.

Comment: I'd say this is case to case. I'd like to think if that background-image or button is re-used again outside of the marketing banner then definitely a separate component. Then you can design rules around spacing of component in component. Fortunately if you work with frameworks like React you can just decide what's a component not on a CSS but on a React Component level. So if you're button's a React component then it will be as well in CSS.